# Auto-commenting on newline, SublimeText

Tags: comments, sublimetext

Could someone point me how to make SublimeText insert comment continuation double-slashes when I enter a new line while inside a comment block?

```
// I have comments like this, and when I enter a '\n'
// it break's out of comment-entering mode 
like this (drops slashes, cursor stays at leftmost column)

// and I want to have them automatically inserted after hiting '\n'
// like this
```

I might have changed that on accident while tweaking preference file, and I don't know how to set it back.

here is my user **prefs**:

```
{
"animation_enabled": false,
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
"auto_complete_delay": 200,
"auto_complete_size_limit": 2097152,
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "<",
        "selector": "text.html"
    },
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source.python"
    },
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source.javascript"
    }
],
"bold_folder_labels": true,
"caret_extra_bottom": 1,
"caret_extra_top": 1,
"caret_extra_width": 0,
"caret_style": "solid",
"color_scheme": "Packages/User/base16-compact.dark (SL).tmTheme",
"copy_with_empty_selection": false,
"default_line_ending": "unix",
"drag_text": false,
"draw_white_space": "none",
"fade_fold_buttons": false,
"font_face": "Inconsolata",
"font_size": 10,
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage",
    "Diff",
    "DocBlockr",
    "Markdown",
    "Shell Command"
],
"indent_guide_options":
[
    "draw_normal"
],
"line_padding_bottom": 1,
"line_padding_top": 1,
"logging_level": "error",
"margin": 0,
"match_brackets_content": false,
"remember_open_files": false,
"scroll_past_end": true,
"scroll_speed": 0,
"shift_tab_unindent": true,
"show_encoding": true,
"show_line_endings": true,
"soda_classic_tabs": true,
"spell_check": false,
"tab_size": 2,
"theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme",
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"tree_animation_enabled": false,
"trim_automatic_white_space": false,
"use_tab_stops": true
}
```

Comment: you might just need to remove all of the code and replace it with `{}` and press CTRL+S to save it. it should do the revert.

Comment: @Viscocent good hint! Cleared the file, and added it back line by line. It was `DocBlockr` plugin issue. Commenting that line (39) in `ignored_packages` list seems to do the trick. Thanks man.

Comment: it was definitely `DocBlockr` bug, reinstalled the plugin, and got old behavior back. I can use it's code-auto-documentation features, and 'normal commenting behavior' while outside doc strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just type this command:

```
CTRL + /
```

single line comments are `single line`, if you want to use another line use the `multi-line` comment.

```
/* */
```

to **revert** your **preference**:

remove all of the code on your user preference and replace it with {} and press CTRL+S to save it. it should do the revert.

Comment: OP wants it inserted automatically, only when inside a comment block

Comment: that's why there is a function called `multi-line` comment for that

Comment: many people I know prefer to use `//` comments to block around large comment areas, for example. If it's what the user *wants* to do, you don't tell him to do something else...

Comment: @*: in both cases (single/multi line) it ignores inserting comment-continuations after new line is inserted while in comment block. I had it insert slashes when in single-line-mode, and asterixes when in multi-line-mode. That's broken now.

Comment: @nikolav `Sublime Text 2 or 3`?

Comment: @Viscocent: sublimetext3

Comment: @nikolav - did you mess with the default settings somehow? do you want a copy of the default settings?

Comment: @Viscocent yes, changed ~60 lines in preferences.user, none of which relates to this matter.

Comment: @nikolav `preferences.user` not ` preferences.default` right? `preferences.user` is empty by default right? i dont see any problems, but can you post your `preferences.user` code too

Comment: @Viscocent correct, `preferences.user`, added stuff to it.

Answer (score 14):

The [DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) package adds this functionality. If you remove it from your 'ignored_packages', that should fix it!

(nb. I see from the comments above that this did indeed fix it, but I'm putting this here as an answer, because it's easy to miss the comments & took me a while to figure out that this functionality came from DocBlockr rather than Sublime Text itself)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the OP correctly, what we want is, let's say we have this:

```cpp
int foo; // a foo|
```

Treat the `|` as a cursor. And if we hit return at the trailing end of the line we automatically get

```cpp
int foo; // a foo
         // |
```

This is the functionality I've been trying to look for anyway. I found that the package [DoxyDoxygen](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/DoxyDoxygen) conveniently does this for me.